# Pattern for extracting data from unstructured message

Tags: c#, algorithm

One of our applications receives data sent in by sensors. By inspecting the contents of a message, the application must figure out what type of message it is looking at and what version of the firmware the sensor is running on. Newer firmware versions send extra data and must be handled differently.

I've provided examples below showing different versions of data messages as well as a configuration message that uses a different structure.

You can see that some data is comma-separated while some it is separated by new lines. There are also markers in the message that are useful for determining message type.

Given that we cannot change the message structure and that the messages do not indicate their firmware version, I'm looking for suggestions and examples of clear, maintainable, extensible methods of interpreting the data. The best we can do is handle things as gracefully as possible on our end.

**Old version of normal message**

```
[MSG]
4 031116 080423

543215432154321
3711mV
30
1,0,0

[READINGS]
00451,00450,00402,06017
00000,021116 083000
00000
00000
00000
00000,031116 080000
[MSGEND]
```

**Newer version of normal message**

```
[MSG]
4 031116 080423

543215432154321
3711mV
30
1,0,0
**0000006216**  <- Extra data added on extra line

[READINGS]
00451,00450,00402,06017
00000,021116 083000
00000
00000
00000
00000,031116 080000
[MSGEND]
```

**Configuration report**

```
[MSG]
2 050416 194503

3913mV
30
1,1,0
0000006216

[CONFIG]
543215432154321
234,15,0037,01DE,-60,234,15,0037,42B0,-76
[MSGEND]
```

Comment: How is the message identified? Number of total arguments? Arguments per line? Order of arguments? [] Markers? Arguments per marker? Once you've got a clear view of the conditions that determine the message type you can check these and create a more usable message object out of the data.

Comment: The type of message (reading/config) can be determined by the [CONFIG] flag.

The firmware version is more difficult. It depends on looking for extra data expected in newer versions of the firmware.

Comment: Then check the flag first to determine the message type. After that count the number of arguments between [MSG] and [MESSAGETYPE] to determine the firmware version?

Comment: You cant tell you need a method to interpret the content without telling how it should get interpreted. Coding isn't magic. It needs definitions. Does the first line always have 2 spaces in between? Is there always an empty line after that? Is there always a `mV` after 4th line? Is there always a 4th line? 1000000 questions left...

Comment: Perhaps the question isn't clear enough. I said that I'm looking for a pattern for extracting the data. Of course there are many rules that govern the location of data in the message and I'm not expecting any magic. I'm looking for examples of how to define and apply a large number of rules to extract data without it ending up as a huge jumble of repetitive code.

Comment: Read the sensor spec.

Comment: Until you explain why reading the sensor spec is not an option for you, I'm downvoting.

Comment: The sensor is a custom device that was manufactured for the business and there is no definitive spec describing the contents of a message. Rules can be inferred from the existing interpretation software, which is what I am aiming to re-write. I am looking for suggestions on good patterns for implementing interpretation based on a large number of differing rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your general message format is:

```
[MSG]
<one or more lines>
blank line
<one or more lines>
blank line
[SOME TEXT]  // (i.e. [READINGS or CONFIG]
<one or more lines>
[MSGEND]
```

At least, the three messages you showed have that general format.

I would recommend doing this in stages. First, gather data until you get a complete message in the buffer. That is, the message begins with `[MSG]` and ends with `[MSGEND]`. I'm going to ignore the possibility of communication failure or corruption here, because it doesn't fundamentally change the basic idea. *Somehow* get a complete message into a buffer.

Now you can start parsing. It looks like the first line of the message (after the `[MSG]`) contains some information from which you can determine what kind of message it is. In your samples, a normal message starts with a '4' on the first line, and the configuration starts with a '2' on the first line.

The next group of lines seems to give type-specific information. If you know what the message type is, then you know how to interpret this. In the case of your old vs. new normal message, you can tell what type of message it is by the existence of that fifth line.

And, of course, the lines after the `[CONFIG]` or `[READINGS]` give the specific information.

It should be pretty simple to create a general template for message processing:

```
Read "[MSG]"
Read identification information up to a blank line
Read blank line
Read more specific message information -- up to a blank line
Read blank line
Read line with "[CONFIG]" or "[READINGS]"
Read data lines up to "[MSGEND]"
Read "[MSGEND]"
```

If you read those data lines into four different lists, you can then examine the data and determine what type of message it is. From there, branch to the specific function for parsing and processing that particular message type.

You'll end up repeating some code, but you can always abstract that once you've figured out if this is how you want to do the processing.

This is certainly clear and maintainable. Whether it's extensible rather depends on your definition of extensible. With this model, you can easily add new types of messages and their corresponding processing methods, as long as the messages all follow the same general format.

I would caution against trying to create a regular expression that can take a message and split it into its relevant parts. With enough puzzling, you can probably create such a regex. For certain, that regular expression would be nearly unreadable by most, difficult to modify and prove correct, and likely very unforgiving of slight format deviations.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you analyze a large enough sample of messages (say, 100), you will notice a pattern. Unstructured messages carrying sensor readings are very rare.

Once identified, you may find it easiest and cleanest to match messages by type (say, data message and config, based on your example). For instance, this regular expression will match your "old/legacy" OR new message, but not config message. If the message is "new", there will be 2 capture groups - first one with 10-digit firmware, and second one with data (sensor readings). If the message is "old/legacy", the regex will contain only 1 capturing group, with sensor readings:

```
^\[MSG\]\n[\d ]+\n{2}\d{15}\n\d{4}mV\n\d{2}\n\d,\d,\d\n?\*{0,2}(\d{10})?\*{0,2}\n{2}\[READINGS\]\n(?m:([\d\s,]*))\[MSGEND\]$
```

Of course, my example is just that - an example - it needs more data for validation, more capturing groups to determine sensor type, etc; but this is how I would approach your issue.

**Regex Resources:**

Here's a [link](https://regex101.com/r/Pwxiih/1) to this regex on regex101.com.

I also like regexper.com quite a bit for visualization of regex (they are easier to write than read, imho). Here's the same regex [visualized](https://regexper.com/#%5E%5C%5BMSG%5C%5D%5Cn%5B%5Cd%20%5D%2B%5Cn%7B2%7D%5Cd%7B15%7D%5Cn%5Cd%7B4%7DmV%5Cn%5Cd%7B2%7D%5Cn%5Cd%2C%5Cd%2C%5Cd%5Cn%3F%5C*%7B0%2C2%7D(%5Cd%7B10%7D)%3F%5C*%7B0%2C2%7D%5Cn%7B2%7D%5C%5BREADINGS%5C%5D%5Cn(%5B%5Cd%5Cs%2C%5D*)%5C%5BMSGEND%5C%5D%24).

Note, I removed the multi-line flag - `(?m:` - from visualization for data capture group. It is not strictly necessary.